# Why is toggle todo not working in Redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

So, I have been working through Dan Abramov's Redux tutorial where you build a simple todo application. Here is the code for the main render function,

```
const todo = (state, action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case 'ADD_TODO':
            return {
                id: action.id, 
                text: action.text, 
                completed: false
            }
        case 'TOGGLE_TODO': 
            if(state.id !== action.id){
                return state
            }
            return {...state,
                completed: !state.completed
            }

        default:
            return state
    }
}

const todos = (state = [], action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case "ADD_TODO": 
            return [
                ...state, 
                todo(undefined, action)
            ]
        case "TOGGLE_TODO": 
            return state.map(t => {
                todo(t, action)
            })
        default: 
            return state;
    }
}

const visibilityFilter = (state = 'SHOW_ALL', action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case 'SET_VISIBILITY_FILTER': 
            return action.filter
        default:
            return state
    }
}


const todoApp = combineReducers({
    visibilityFilter, 
    todos
});

const store = createStore(todoApp);

const FilterLink = ({
    filter, 
    currentFilter,
    children
}) => {
    if(filter === currentFilter){
        return <span>{children}</span>
    }
    return (
        <a href='#' onClick={e => {
            e.preventDefault();
            store.dispatch({
                type: 'SET_VISIBILITY_FILTER', 
                filter
            })
        }}>
            {children}
        </a>
    )
}

const Todo = ({
    onClick, 
    completed, 
    text
}) => (
    <li onClick={(onClick)}
    style={{textDecoration: completed ? 'line-through' : 'none'}}>
        {text}
    </li>
);

const TodoList = ({
    todos, 
    onTodoClick
}) => (
    <ul>
        {todos.map(todo => 
            <Todo key={todo.id} {...todo}
            onClick={() => onTodoClick(todo.id)} />
        )}
    </ul>
);

const getVisibleTodos = (todos, filter) => {
    switch(filter){
        case 'SHOW_ALL':
            return todos;
        case 'SHOW_COMPLETED':
            return todos.filter(
                t => t.completed
            )
        case 'SHOW_ACTIVE':
            return todos.filter(
                t => !t.completed
            )
    }
}

let nextTodoId = 0;
class TodoApp extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const {
            todos, 
            visibilityFilter
        } = this.props
        const visibleTodos = getVisibleTodos(todos, visibilityFilter);
        return (
            <div>
                <input ref={text => {
                    this.input = text;
                }} />
                <button onClick={() => {
                    store.dispatch({
                        type:"ADD_TODO", 
                        text: this.input.value, 
                        id: nextTodoId++
                    });
                    this.input.value = '';
                }}>Add a todo
                </button>
                <TodoList todos={visibleTodos} onTodoClick={id => store.dispatch({
                    type: 'TOGGLE_TODO', 
                    id
                })} />
                <p>
                    Show: 
                    {' '}
                    <FilterLink filter='SHOW_ALL' currentFilter={visibilityFilter}>
                        All
                    </FilterLink>
                    {' '}
                    <FilterLink filter='SHOW_COMPLETED' currentFilter={visibilityFilter}>
                        Completed
                    </FilterLink>
                    {' '}
                    <FilterLink filter='SHOW_ACTIVE' currentFilter={visibilityFilter}>
                        Active
                    </FilterLink>
                </p>
            </div>
        )
    }
}



const render = () => {
    console.log(store.getState());
    ReactDOM.render(<TodoApp {...store.getState()}/>, document.getElementById('root'));
}

store.subscribe(render);
render();
```

When I try to toggle the todo, I get the following error,

> index.js:170 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Now, when I tried logging out this.props.todos on the event of my trying to toggle a todo, it returns undefined. This is the reason why I get the error, because for some reason this.props.todos is not being passed on the click event. However, I went through the course notes and I have the exact same code. What am I doing wrong here? And how do I fix it?

Comment: can you see data when you console.log(this.props.todos)

Comment: is it on github ?

Comment: So, when it renders the first time and I then add a new todo, it works fine. However, when I click on one of the todos to toggle its completed status, it throws an error and at this point this.props.todos logs undefined.

Comment: @abhirathore2006 - https://github.com/tayiorbeii/egghead.io_redux_course_notes/blob/master/13-React_Todo_List_Example_Toggling_a_Todo.md
So here are the course notes for this specific lesson. However, there is no complete source code for this lesson. Only the bits of code pertinent to the lesson are provided on the page.

Comment: @ZaidHumayun provide your complete code

Comment: @abhirathore2006 - I have provided the complete code, albeit with a few changes where I have split the main TodoApp into smaller components.

Comment: console.log the state and action in toggle_todo action under both todos and todo reducer and see what you get there

Comment: one more thing, what is your visibility filter set ? if its ShowActive then you may need to check the todos before running map over it.

Answer (score 1):

Is this the example you are following? https://github.com/reactjs/redux/tree/master/examples/todos

Not sure if it is down to this, but in your `Todo` you might want to remove the `()` around onClick.

```
const Todo = ({
    onClick, 
    completed, 
    text
}) => (
    <li onClick={ onClick } /* <- this bit */
    style={{textDecoration: completed ? 'line-through' : 'none'}}>
        {text}
    </li>
);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your todos reducer for the "TOGGLE_TODO" case. You have this code:

```
return state.map(t => {todo(t, action)})
```

The brackets are unnecessary and cause the arrow function to expect a return statement. Since there isn't a return statement, the return value is undefined, so you get an array of undefined values.

Change it to

```
return state.map(t => todo(t, action));
```